# Does my iOS 8 framework need its own code signing for distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload my iOS 8 app to the app store for distribution. My app contains a framework created with Xcode 6. I am getting the following provisioning profile error from the uploader tool.

"ERROR ITMS-90161: Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.auraishere.AuraClient [Payload/hipgroup.app/Frameworks/AuraCore.framework] is invalid. Missing code-signing certificate."

The archiving works fine and I am using a freshly created distribution certificate and profile for both the target and the project. The app id is specific to the bundle name and not a wildcard one.

The framework compiles in a separate framework project successfully using a different organisation's development certificate. Do I need to compile it using a distribution certificate for that organisation or is that not necessary?

I have a script that creates a fat binary using the lipo tool to support multiple architectures and copies the fat binary to my app's project folder. I don't think this is the problem but I have included it in case.

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Build framework for iPhoneOS
xcodebuild -target AuraCore ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# Build framework for iPhoneSimulator
xcodebuild -target AuraCore -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Build the universal library
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Copy the .framework folder of iphoneos
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Delete the library for iphoneos
rm "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Move the Universal Library into our framework
mv "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/"

# Copy the framework
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"
rm -Rf "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../aura-ios-demo/{PROJECT_NAME}.framework"
cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../aura-ios-demo"

if [ -d "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../concierge" ]; then
    echo "dir exsits"
# Copy the framework
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"
rm -Rf "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../concierge/{PROJECT_NAME}.framework"
cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../concierge"
fi
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1085104#1085104) developer forum thread:
"Frameworks do need to be code signed but Xcode takes care of this for you.
They don't need any extra profiles or app ID to run.  The only thing you need to do in order to use them is to ensure they are copied properly during the build process with the extra build phase."

Is the "Code Sign On Copy" box checked in the build phase?

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought. Yes I do have the code sign on copy ticked for my framework. The only difference is the name of the Build phase. My is "Copy Files" whereas yours is "Embed Frameworks" - don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, it makes. How did you add your embedded framework? Is it presenting in the 'Embedded Framework' and even in the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' and  part of General tab? It should be presented in both place.

Comment: Ok it was in the embedded binaries section I have removed it and then added it via the Linked Frameworks and Libraries + button. But I now don't have the Embed Frameworks part in the build phase.

Comment: Tried to reupload a couple of times with the same error. [Could it be this issue?](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios-8/) If so has anyone solved this? Should I update to Xcode 6.2 or 6.3? Thanks

Comment: It's up to you, how you name this section. Originally is this section named as "Copy Files", in some examples is named as "Embed Frameworks", or as "Copy Frameworks" in Alamofire. Important is content of this section, not its name.

Comment: What if I don't want to force code-signing because I received a 3rd-party framework that is already signed? It seems that iTunes connect rejects the binary if all the code is not signed by the same identity.

Comment: I'm in a catch--22 because I keep getting "ERROR ITMS-90161" when trying to upload my app -- regardless of how the framework was signed.  It's doing this because the "copy phase strip" is skipped if the framework is signed.  Part of that stripping appears to be stripping the framework DRM, which would allow the APP to sign the framework with its own cert.

Comment: To add some confusion: in XCode 8 it seems it doesn't matter much whether you embed a framework in General -> Embedded binaries or Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks, because if you drag a .framework into one of these places, it automatically appears in the other place also. I guess, XCode is syncing both those settings. Anyway, linking is not enough - it's just linking and your framework won't be nor signed nor available on the target device unless you package (embed) it together with the app. But I might be wrong...