# xcode how to ignore signing of third party libary

Tags: xcode

[image]

These red dots doesn't hurt bug simply annoying. How to make xcode ignore them?

Comment: Search for "signing" in the build config

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès and then? I have no issue with my own project code signing. Those were the dev team hash of third-party library.

Comment: May be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731267/does-my-ios-8-framework-need-its-own-code-signing-for-distribution